# Importing file to array

Tags: c#, arrays, file

I want the user to be able to chose a text file written in a certain way (1 number per line) and then have the file converted into an array. I have bits and pieces of it working but I cant get it to all work at the same time. Any help would be appreciated.

```
private void Load_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int counter = 0;
        string line;
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        string fileName = "";

        //OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        //ofd.Filter = "TXT File|*.txt";
        //ofd.Title = "Open File";

        // if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        // {
        File_Label.Text = "C:/Users/Neilan/Desktop/sample.txt";
            //fileName = "@" + ofd.SafeFileName;

        //MessageBox.Show(ofd.FileName);

        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Neilan\Desktop\sample.txt");


            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Unsorted_Box.Text += line + ", "; 
                //list.Add(int.Parse(fileName));
                counter++;
            }
            dataArray = list.ToArray();

       // }

    }
```

Comment: How does the file looks like? What is ur expected output??

Comment: This should not be marked as the duplicate as it is two days older than the other question

Answer (score 2):

You can do this.

```
var numberarray = File.ReadAllLines("stringpath").Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Looking at your code, I guess you want to show these values in comma separated format to user. You can achieve this with following code snippet.

```
Unsorted_Box.Text = String.Join(",", numberarray.ToArray());
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by one line

```
   var resultArray = Array.ConvertAll(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("filename.type"), str => int.Parse(str));
```

Instead of "filename.type" you can put something like `File_Label.Text`